# Add image to Submit input with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, sticky-footer

Hi I have the following code

```
<input type="submit" name="btnCheckOut" value="Buy >>" id="btnCheckOut" />
```

I don't have direct access to the source code, but I would like to add a image *"money.png"* in front of the *"Buy"* text.

How would one do this with Jquery?

Comment: I would use &raquo; instead of >>, just looks a little nicer IMO.  

If I were in your shoes I would just make the image, I don't think you can really add an icon to a submit button too nicely.
`<input type="image" src="img.png" />`

Make img.png have your icon followed by 'Buy >>'

Comment: A much better option is create an image which contains Buy and small image ,like you see the shopping cart symbol in Amazon.

Comment: Sadly I don't have any options for changing it to a an image. My only way of editing is with Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la Aaron Huran's solution, but in JQuery:

```
$(this).css('background', "url('/myimage.png') no-repeat top left").css('padding', '2px 8px');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS by adding a background image to the "submit" element.

```
submit {

    background: url('/myimage.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

Comment: Or with JQuery `$(this).css('background', "url('/myimage.png') no-repeat top left").css('padding', '2px 8px');`

(since you can only use jquery)

Comment: If he can add Javascript for jQuery, he can probably add actual CSS too.

Comment: True, but he can't access the HTML, so you never know

Comment: Rob your way solved it. Jquery way. please leave an answer.

And I did try with css, but again i don't have direct access to the source, so it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

By "in front" do you mean in front of the `<input/>` or in front of the actual text (i.e. within the input)?

If it's the former then this should do:

```
$('input[name=btnCheckOut]').before('<img src="money.png"/>');
```

If it's the latter then you should use a `<button>` instead since it allows almost any elements within it:

```
$('input[name=btnCheckOut]').before(
    '<button name="btnCheckOut"><img src="money.png"/>Buy &gt;&gt;</button>'
).remove();
```

Comment: @Aaron, hence why the button is being added dynamically, via jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Use before() to inject your image before the input tag.

http://api.jquery.com/before/

```
$('#btnCheckOut').before('<img src="money.png" id="..." />');
```

PS
If you want the image to be clickable too you have to manage it via jQuery too by binding the click event.